# Tag wiki should provide guidance on [zoom] vs [zoom-meeting]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-wiki

I've noticed that we have both [zoom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom) and a [zoom-meeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) tags. Some questions about the Zoom videoconferencing software are tagged with [zoom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom), and some with [zoom-meeting](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom-meeting) -- there is currently no consistent usage.

How should these tags be used?

I think it would be useful to pick a consistent usage, and edit the tag wiki for [zoom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom) to provide guidance on correct usage.  I tried making one proposal (see [here](https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1002635)) but so far reactions have been mixed, so I ask here to find out whether people think it would be useful to provide guidance, and if so, what guidance should be provided.

Comment: I've approved your tag edit, and will clean up the zoom tag

Answer (score 5):

Speaking from experience, you really need a moderator to rename the tag. Excerpt guidance is always helpful, but the tag needs to be clear. The reason is that few people pay attention to excerpts and they don't show for anyone using a mobile browser.

I would suggest renaming [zoom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/zoom) to [enlargement-zoom](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/enlargement-zoom) and synonyming, which should solve the problem for good. Otherwise you'll be endlessly cleaning the tag up.

Comment: Enlargement-zoom is a good option.